# automount SSHFS on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sshfs

looks like all the "automount SSHFS" are outdated and not working anymore on today desktops.

If I have a microSD card, that is shared via SFTP on an rpi, how can I auto-mount it on eg.: Ubuntu 20.04 desktops?

Tried with ex.:

```
sshfs#MYUSER@192.168.8.3:/stuff/ /media/user/stuff/  fuse.sshfs noauto,x-systemd.automount,users,idmap=user,IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,reconnect,port=22 0 0
```

but it doesn't work.. what only works so far is:

```
sshfs#MYUSER@192.168.8.3:/stuff/ /media/user/stuff/ fuse defaults,auto,allow_other,noatime,port=22,IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa,user 0 0
```

but this requires me to do a "mount -a".. which is not very automatic :)

**The question**: as a normal user, how can I mount an SSHFS share only on demand? So if I am in that directory (in eg.: GNOME os in the terminal, ls or cd or "cp from tothatshare") Havin SSH key login with no password.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I mount an SSHFS share only on demand?

Typically, you do that using systemd (auto)mounts.

You just add a file to your /etc/systemd/system, containing

```
[Unit]
Description=SSHFS mount
Requires=network-online.target

[Mount]
What=sshfs#MYUSER@192.168.8.3:/stuff/
Where=/media/user/stuff/
Type=sshfs
Options=allow_other,noatime,port=22,IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The file *must* be named `media-user-stuff.mount` (i.e. take what is in `Where=`, remove the root /, then replace all / with - and end with .mount)

That's a systemd mount file. You *can* now mount that directory using systemd (but you don't want that, so let's not do that).

Instead, we also write an systemd.automount file: That will make systemd "pseudo-mount" something at the `Where=`. The first time something tries to access that, the actual mounting takes place.

so, `/etc/systemd/system/media-user-stuff.automount`:

```
[Unit]
Description=user media automount

[Automount]
Where=/media/user/stuff

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

which you finally enable using `systemctl enable --now media-user-stuff.automount`. It will hence be "pre-mounted" every system boot.

> **as a normal user**, how can I …

not at all; the automount logic depends on being able to monitor access to a directory, and that takes root privileges. Far as I can see, a wrapper that eradicates that need is not built in currently.

---

Word about SSHFS: Honestly, there's probably better network file systems; SSHfs really likes to hang and be unrecoverable on connection loss, it's not "clean" in a lot of ways, you can lose data (happened to me!) without noticing, and it's *very slow, actually*.

Maybe use a different network file system. Samba isn't hard to set up these days.